# sum rows values then put the results in the next one

Tags: php

My app is about importing an excel file, and inserting the fields in the database except that I would like to add a line below each level(Niveau) to sum.

i would like to have an idea how to make it

i made a query, it works perfectly in mysql, but i need to add a row at the bottom of the table that contains the sum of values

Thank you

```
 <td><?php echo gmdate('H:i:s', $t[11]); ?></td>
                                    <tr><?php $sql="select user, equipe, (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(agent_time))) AS agent_time , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(wait))) AS wait , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talk))) AS talk , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(dispo))) AS dispo , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pause))) AS pause , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(dead))) AS dead , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ps))) AS ps , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pp))) AS pp , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pb))) AS pb , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pam))) AS pam , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pa))) as PA , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(login))) AS plogin , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pf))) as pf , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(padmin))) AS padmin , (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pf))) AS pf, (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ppan))) AS ppan from agent_time where equipe='Niveau 3'  ";
                                    $x = $conn->query($sql);
                                    ?></tr>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgxaX.png)

Comment: and what is your current result? Please add code here.

Comment: i'am stuck , i would like a suggestion how i can do it , thanks

Comment: i made this query , i tried it in mysql it works perfectly , now i need to add a row at the bottom of my table that contains the sum of values

Comment: @madrid - Please share what you have tried so far. What code snippets didn't work and what errors were produced?

Answer (score 0):

For what I see, you want to display the last row of an html table (representing your db table) with the query you made. The simplier way would be to separate the behaviour in a function in charge of creating that last row as follow:

```
function sumLastRow() {
    $sql="select 
            user, 
            equipe, 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(agent_time))) AS agent_time , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(wait))) AS wait , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talk))) AS talk , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(dispo))) AS dispo , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pause))) AS pause , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(dead))) AS dead , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ps))) AS ps , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pp))) AS pp , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pb))) AS pb , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pam))) AS pam , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pa))) as PA , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(login))) AS plogin , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pf))) as pf , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(padmin))) AS padmin , 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(pf))) AS pf, 
            (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ppan))) AS ppan 
        from agent_time 
        where equipe='Niveau 3'";

    $x = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $x->fetch_object();

    if ($result) {
        $response = "<tr>";
        $aux = "<td>%v</td>";
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $response .= str_replace("%v", $value, $aux);
        }

        $response .= "</tr>";
    }

    return $response;
}
```

After that, just print the value returned by the function at the last row of the table.